# How to make nodemailer reusable in multiple module?

Tags: node.js, express, nodemailer

I have implemented `nodemailer` after the user registration, in the following way:

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
        user: process.env.EMAIL_USERNAME,
        pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASSWORD
    }
});

let mailOptions = {
    from: process.env.EMAIL_USERNAME,
    to: user.email,
    subject: 'Verify your account',
    text: 'Click here for verify your account'
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
        return console.log(error);
    }
});
```

I don't like much this code because if I need to send an email in another `module`, I need to rewrite all the stuff above.

Since I'm new to `NodeJS`, I would like to know if I can remove this code redundancy make something like a `utility` or maybe an `helper` class. The goal is import the `wrapper` class and call a simple function to send the email.

Which is the best way to handle that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use module.exports as follow :

create common service mail.js and write your mail sent code here

mails.js

```
module.exports = function (){
 // mail sent code
}
```

require mail.js where you write mail sent code in other service and call mail sent function

otherService.js

```
var mail = require('mail.js') // require mail sent in other service where you want to send mail
mail.sent() // call function of mail.js
```

Comment: `mails.js` should be added in `services` folder?

Comment: It's depend on your project structure but ideally yes it should be in service folder

Answer (score 6):

I refactored your code to look like below and then save it as **mail.js**

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
        user: process.env.EMAIL_USERNAME,
        pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASSWORD
    }
});

let sendMail = (mailOptions)=>{
  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
        return console.log(error);
    }
  });
};

module.exports = sendMail;
```

in Your other modules, say **activation.js**

```
var mailer = require('./mail.js');

mailer({
    from: process.env.EMAIL_USERNAME,
    to: user.email,
    subject: 'Verify your account',
    text: 'Click here for verify your account'
};);
```

Answer (score 3):

I have created a class for this:

```js
import NodeMailer from 'nodemailer'
import emailConfig from '../../config/mail' // read email credentials from your config

class EmailSender {
    transport

    constructor() {
        this.transport = NodeMailer.createTransport({
            host: emailConfig.MAIL_HOST,
            port: emailConfig.MAIL_PORT,
            auth: {
                user: emailConfig.MAIL_USERNAME,
                pass: emailConfig.MAIL_PASSWORD,
            },
        })
    }

    async sendMessage(to, subject, text, html) {
        let mailOptions = {
            from: emailConfig.MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS,
            to,
            subject,
            text,
            html,
        }

        await this.transport.sendMail(mailOptions)
    }
}

export default new EmailSender()
```

Now you can implement it in your any routes:

```js
router.get('/email', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        await EmailSender.sendMessage(
            'bijaya@bijaya.com',
            'Hello world',
            'test',
            '<h1>Test</h1>'
        )

        return res.status(200).send('Successfully sent email.')
    } catch (exception) {
        return res.status(500).send(exception.message)
    }
})
```